# How do I make house appear in the happy home show case because it was empty?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I went on Animal Crossing New leaf today and i tried the Happy Home show case but none of the houses appeared. Does this feature not work anymore? Can some one please help!

Answer (score 1):

This feature does work. You have to meet someone via Streetpass to get their house. Once you have met someone with Streetpass, go to the HHA showcase. You will find 1 or more people standing on the north-west corner. Speak to them, and they will tell you where their house is. Go to where they said, and you can see their house, but not take anything.